# Custom Cell not nil in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created a custom cell in UITableView inside StoryBoard but its always return value not NULL(NIL)

```
eg: CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
NSLog(@"%@",cell);

it return --> <CustomCell: 0x8352480; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 84); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x834f680>>
```

I don't know why, i think customCell return nil when cell is not value;

Anybody say why, why customCell is not nil

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because from a storyboard, when you call dequeReuseableCellWithIdentifier: it creates the cell  if there isn't one in the reuse queue.

So you always get a cell by calling this method, not a nil.